# why there is not pre-defined border style in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

why there is not pre-defined border style in bootstrap? Or This is some but I didn't find?

My owner style looks weird and not compatible with bootstrap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap is mainly designed to create a stable and consistent layout, it is not a complete website template, stylings are specifically left out of it to ensure it is adaptable to any website.  Its the choice of the designer to add additional stylings.

You can customize bootstrap to make it suit your style here

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html for Bootstrap 2.3.2
or 
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ for Bootstrap 3

If there was a specific way that bootstrap was affecting your own css or html you should post an example or a website link to help me be more specific.